# In chart.js , change color of chart by clicking button

Tags: chart.js

In chart.js, is it possible to change the color of a chart (theme) by clicking a button? 
Let's say I have buttons named 'dark mode', 'light mode' when I click 'dark mode' button, the chart color changes to dark color.

I can't find any example of it by googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new chart or update your chart with the new colors in the options or in your dataset. There's no function with changes all colors to a dark mode, you have to change all colors on your own.

I can't give you all the possible color options, there's simply too many. Just look at the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) or maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58875606/11989020) for a few examples. You can for sure change e.g. all the dataset and background colors.